# How can I iteratively apply the function on a data in c++?

Tags: c++, function, loops, vector, iteration

I'm just looking for a general pseudo-code type in which if I have a data type of `vector<vector<double>> X`and it needs to iteratively go through a function `myFunction(vector<vector<double>> &X)` that returns the same data type until a certain condition on `X` is met or until n'th iterations.

So, suppose let `X(1) = myFunction(X)`, then feed it again to get

`X(2) = myFunction(X(1))`, then feed it again to get

`X(3) = myFunction(X(2))`, and repreat until certain conditions say

`myCondition(X(k)) = true` or until n'th iteration has been done and stops at X(n)

How could I implement it?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? How did your attempts work or not work? And if you haven't done it yet, then please take some time to [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> x;
unsigned int numIterators = 100u; // for example
do
{
    x = myFunction(x);
} while(!Condition(x) && --numIterators)
```

And `bool Condition(const std::vector<std::vector<double>>&)` checks the condition that you want to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this:

```
typedef vector<vector<double>> datatype;
datatype myFunction( datatype X ,int iteration ,int n ){
    if( iteration== n ) return X;
    /// do some operations with X
    myFunction( X , iteration+1 ,n );
}
```

From main function, you may call like this:

```
  // define vector X and no of iterations- n.
  datatype ans=myFunction(X,0,n);
```